# How to to specify pronunciations for OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, text-to-speech

The text-to-speech function on Mac OS X Lion is quite good, although sometimes it misses the just-right pronunciation of a word.

Is there a way to specify a pronunciation for certain words or phrases in Lion?

For example, let's say my friend's name is "Tony", and the voice for OS X (Alex) pronounces Tony "tooney". Is there a way that I can set Tony to be pronounced the same way Alex pronounces "Toe Nee"?

Comment: Type it phonetically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open **Applications > Services > VoiceOver Utility** and go to Speech > Pronunciation. Add a subsitution for "Tony" and tell it to pronounce it as "toe nee".

[image]

Interestingly, my computer running 10.7.3 with the Alex voice pronounces Tony correctly. Because of this, I wasn't able to test this solution, so it may not work.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for. My computer pronounces it fine too, just using that as an example. Cheers!

Comment: Ah, I missed that somehow. There's also some hidden app somewhere I was *just using* to manipulate the exact phonetics of words, and I'm really annoyed that I can't find it anywhere!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the terminal. Try running "say tony" in the terminal, and you wont get your new pronunciation.... and ideas on how to make this happen?

Comment: This is a great answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. Is there something I am missing? Some command to set my changes? I tried closing applications and reopening them, then I tried restarting the computer, but it has no effect. (I am running OSX 10.8.5 on my Mac.)

Comment: The voice over utility only impacts how voice over service handles pronunciations, it unfortunately does not affect the text-to-speech service (including the `say` command in terminal)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `[[inpt PHON]]`:

```
 [[inpt PHON]]_t1OW ~n2EY.[[inpt TEXT]]
```

See the [Speech Synthesis Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/Phonemes/Phonemes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH9-SW1).

If you download the Auxiliary Tools for Xcode package from https://developer.apple.com/downloads, you can use the Repeat After Me application to convert text to the phonetic syntax:

[image]