# In terminal, how to get "say" to say things "right" ? ie using custom phonetics?

Tags: terminal, text, voice

I'd like to use "say" in the terminal to create audio files with a custom phonetic dictionary, or at the very least, say things how I think they should sound. From my understanding, [this can't be accomplished through the "Voice Over Utility" configuration screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46552/how-to-to-specify-pronunciations-for-os-x-lion/46554#comment61510_46554).

So to have say "speak" things correctly, I'm willing to:

- use a custom phonetic dictionary or
- change my input text to some phonetic variant

For example, I'd like to be able to have the word "colossians" said as I expect it, which is phonetically something like "kuh LOSH uhnz" **without** the pauses that the spaces cause in the word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Speech Synthesis Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) describes the [embedded speech commands](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/FineTuning/FineTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH5-SW10) that you can use to adjust how the speech synthesis engines process your input text.

The `[[inpt PHON]]` command enables the use of [phonemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/Phonemes/Phonemes.html) and [phoneme modifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/FineTuning/FineTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH5-DontLinkElementID_3).

For example, the following text includes a phonemic version of your chosen word  (select the text, Control-click, and select Speech > Start Speaking to hear it directly in *Safari*):

```
If you don't like how I say "colossians",
then perhaps you will be satisfied with
"[[inpt PHON]]kUH2lAASUHnz[[inpt TEXT]]".
```

This syntax is accepted by the *say* command in the shell and AppleScript (though you will have to modify the (above) use of single- and double-quotes to suit the string literal syntax of your chosen context).

Comment: You can convert English text to the phonetic representation with Repeat After Me.app. It used to be installed in /Developer/Applications/ before Xcode 4.3, but is now part of the auxiliary tools package at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/.

Comment: It'd be nice if we could use the International Phonetic Alphabet (which is in Unicode) to do this instead of the ASCII-based version Repeat After Me uses.